# How to retrieve file versions content using SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am not able to fetch file content of different versions using Bearer token.

I tried to get content by using this endpoint:

```
https://{host}.sharepoint.com/_vti_history/{version-id}/{file-path}
```

and I got such a response:

```
401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

However, I am able to download this file in my browser using the same endpoint. I noticed that it sends some cookies in headers.

How can I do this using access token?

Comment: you ever figure this out?